Do you know any Madhva sampradaya grihastha gurus?
I want to know if there are any madhva sampradaya grihastha gurus, who can teach tantra or bramhajnan. I am starting a bounty answer only if you know one..

It depends where you live.. go to any raghavendra mutt and learn the basic tenants of madhva sampradaya from appointed preist there or goto UM there are levels based on your qualification you can choose gurus accordingly.. if you are highly proficient in sanskrit please read the scripture of madhva muni Raghavendra swamigal, vyasa raja, and jayateertha.. and reach out to either swamiji for clarification or respective author of the book

Thanks Sir..I am not asking about scriptural knowledge..I am asking about mantra and tantra vidya and yoga

This
https://madhwaprameyamahodadhi.blogspot.com/
website might offer what you are looking for.
